# Why does "rake elasticsearch:start" timeout but still start an elasticsearch node?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, elasticsearch

After months of elasticsearch and rspec working perfectly together, I'm getting lots of new and seemingly random `Faraday:TimeoutError` errors when I run `rspec`, and I'm trying to troubleshoot the problem. I started with a *classic* restart of my entire system. From there I checked to see what elasticsearch was doing. First I ran this:

```
$ curl localhost:9200

{
  "status" : 200,
  "name" : "Rigellian Recorder",
  "cluster_name" : "elasticsearch_eliduke",
  "version" : {
    "number" : "1.4.2",
    "build_hash" : "927caff6f05403e936c20bf4529f144f0c89fd8c",
    "build_timestamp" : "2014-12-16T14:11:12Z",
    "build_snapshot" : false,
    "lucene_version" : "4.10.2"
  },
  "tagline" : "You Know, for Search"
}
```

So somehow I already have elasticsearch running immediately after a fresh restart. Is that somehow being started on a reboot? I thought maybe something could be in my `.bash_profile`, but nothing there.

Then I checked my elasticsearch test port:

```
$ curl localhost:9250

curl: (7) Failed to connect to localhost port 9250: Connection refused
```

Clearly, the test node is not running, so I tried to start it using the [chewy](https://github.com/toptal/chewy) rake task:

```
$ rake elasticsearch:start

Starting 2 Elasticsearch nodes...........rake aborted!
Timeout::Error: execution expired
/Users/eliduke/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0/gems/elasticsearch-extensions-0.0.17/lib/elasticsearch/extensions/test/cluster.rb:222:in `block (2 levels) in __wait_for_status'
/Users/eliduke/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0/gems/elasticsearch-extensions-0.0.17/lib/elasticsearch/extensions/test/cluster.rb:220:in `loop'
/Users/eliduke/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0/gems/elasticsearch-extensions-0.0.17/lib/elasticsearch/extensions/test/cluster.rb:220:in `block in __wait_for_status'
/Users/eliduke/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0/gems/elasticsearch-extensions-0.0.17/lib/elasticsearch/extensions/test/cluster.rb:219:in `__wait_for_status'
/Users/eliduke/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0/gems/elasticsearch-extensions-0.0.17/lib/elasticsearch/extensions/test/cluster.rb:201:in `wait_for_green'
/Users/eliduke/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0/gems/elasticsearch-extensions-0.0.17/lib/elasticsearch/extensions/test/cluster.rb:125:in `start'
/Users/eliduke/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0/gems/elasticsearch-extensions-0.0.17/lib/elasticsearch/extensions/test/cluster/tasks.rb:6:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
/Users/eliduke/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15:in `eval'
/Users/eliduke/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15:in `<main>'
Tasks: TOP => elasticsearch:start
(See full trace by running task with --trace)
```

It seemed like it was going to start correctly as those little dots were crawling across the screen, but then **BONK**! Who knows what is causing it to timeout: it was only attempting to start for maybe 20 or 30 seconds. But then the weird part:

```
$ curl localhost:9250

{
  "status" : 200,
  "name" : "node-1",
  "cluster_name" : "elasticsearch_test",
  "version" : {
    "number" : "1.4.2",
    "build_hash" : "927caff6f05403e936c20bf4529f144f0c89fd8c",
    "build_timestamp" : "2014-12-16T14:11:12Z",
    "build_snapshot" : false,
    "lucene_version" : "4.10.2"
  },
  "tagline" : "You Know, for Search"
}
```

It started anyway?! So weird. Something seems wrong here, so I thought I'd just throw this out there and see if anyone else has had this problem.

1. Do you know why elasticsearch on port 9200 is already started after reboot?
2. Do you know why `rake elasticsearch:start` would be timing out?
3. Does my `Faraday:TimeoutError` error have any correlation to all this?
4. What is a good next step for troubleshooting this?

Comment: You probably have elasticsearch starting on your machine from the LaunchAgents.  If you installed via homebrew on OSX it'll be in `~/Library/LaunchAgents/`.  Not sure where the "elasticsearch:start" task is coming from - I don't see it at the referenced link.  My guess is that it's starting the server (and succeeding) and the "dots" represent some import tasks.  When you're getting deeper into the imports there's an "import" call thats taking too long and timing out.  I recently added "batch_size" parameter to all my import calls and I'm seeing much better results.

Comment: I think the test cluster that is being started with `rake elasticsearch:start` is still in a "yellow" health status. The dots are from https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch-ruby/blob/2030678fe218c4ebc29d1370edaad9899ccd5cc6/elasticsearch-extensions/lib/elasticsearch/extensions/test/cluster.rb#L278 where it's waiting for green status but never gets it. I have the same problem, and I don't know exactly why the cluster never goes green.

Comment: FWIW you can do `TEST_CLUSTER_NODES=1 rake elasticsearch:start` so it only does 1 node, and that seems to work for me